# What is the difference between Ob and Propter?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, preposition

I am new to learning Latin, and I read on some random Latin site that "ob" means "on account of" or "because of".  But, I thought that "propter" meant "on account of".  Is there a difference in meaning that I don't understand?  Are they just redundant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The causal meaning of these two prepositions developed separately, so the history of their usage is a bit complex.  But in Classical Latin and after, while some authors used the two interchangeably, *ob* became more and more limited to literary language, while *propter* was used in popular language.

## Origins

Silvia Luraghi's paper ["Prepositions in Cause expressions"](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/joll.2005.9.issue-2/joll.2005.9.2.609/joll.2005.9.2.609.xml) traces the development of prepositions used to describe cause, like *ob* and *propter*.  She first describes the difference in original meaning between the two – *propter* spatially means "nearby," so it comes to refer to cause through the idea that "a cause and its effect are contiguous."  She gives this example:

> *abduce me hinc ab hac quantum potest, quam **propter** tantum damnum feci et flagiti*
> "take me hence away from her as soon as you can, **on whose account** I have incurred so much loss and guilt"
> (Bac. 1032).

On the other hand, *ob* originally means "in front of."  So if an observer is trying to look at a landmark, but there is an obstacle in between them, his view of the landmark is "exchanged" for the obstacle, and this is how the word is ultimately connected to cause.  For example:

> *men piacularem oportet fieri **ob** stultitiam tuam, ut meum tergum tuae stultitiae subdas succidaneum?*
> “is it proper that I should be the atonement **for** your folly, so as for you to substitute my back as the scapegoat for your folly?”
> (Pl. Ep. 139-140).

So we see that the two words have different origins.  But what about usage?

## History of usage

In Early Latin, Luraghi finds that *ob* (109 occurrences) is more frequent than *propter* (49 occurrences), but in examination of Plautus, she finds "the onset of a development that took *ob* to be limited to idioms."

This trend continues, she argues, in Classical Latin.  She summarizes:

> The distribution of *ob* and *propter* is of special interest. In certain authors, the two prepositions seem to be equivalent. However, interchangeability of *ob* and *propter* is a comparatively late phenomenon, and may have never been a feature of the spoken language.

She cites Löfsted, who finds that in post-classical times *propter* was the popular word and *ob* the literary word.  But she argues that evidence for this distinction already exists in Classical Latin.  She notes that many classical authors show a distinct preference for one word or the other; for example, Tacitus rarely used *propter*, perhaps indicating that he felt *ob* was more suitable for literary works.

Others used the two fairly evenly – Cicero has *ob* 744 times and *propter* 885 times, though 60% of his usages of *ob* are in conjunction with *rem* or *causam*.

In Late Latin, she points to the absence of *ob* in non-literary texts:

> Non-literary texts offer evidence for the disappearance of *ob*, which only occurs 3 times in the *Mulomedicina Chironis*, and does not occur at all in the *Peregrinatio Aetheriae*.

## Summary

For today's Latin student, perhaps it's simplest to call the two words synonyms – [Bennett's Latin Grammar (§141)](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect141) translates them identically.  Keep in mind that *ob* often goes with *rem* and *causam* ([Gildersleeve and Lodge (§416)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&pg=PA270)), and may sound more "literary."  But if Cicero used both, you certainly can too!

Comment: +1 Great answer. A small note, *ob* is universally used for prefixes.